# Convert timestamp with dots in PHP ("yyyy.mm.dd hh:nn:ss.zzz")

Tags: php, timestamp

I'm trying to convert strings with hungarian datetime format, but no success because of the dot-separators:

```
<?php
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat("YY'.'MM'.'DD HH:MM:II frac", "2020.07.22 22:41:36.258");
$timestamp = $dtime->getTimestamp();
echo("Result: " . $timestamp . "<br>");
?>
```

Isn't it possible **without** "string-replace" like this:
`strtotime(preg_replace("/([0-9]{4})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})/",'${1}-${2}-${3}',$xml->delivery_time))` ?

*(I'm new to PHP 5 and I'm shocked it can not simply convert a common date format. Searched 200+ results, wasted 4+ hours ... no success.)*

Comment: Please, read about date format placeholders, `YY`, `MM` etc are __incorrect__

Comment: *I'm new to PHP 5 and I'm shocked it can not simply convert a common date format* - `"Y.m.d H:i:s.v"`, but I would also wonder why you are using PHP 5?

Comment: @NigelRen OFF It's not my server. I've also suggested the owner to upgrade it to PHP 7 but he has too many old scripts and no time yet to check if there is a problem with the change.

Comment: Tips: `var_dump($dtime, DateTime::getLastErrors());` and [format codes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will also work for PHP versions below 7.3

```
// convert a hungarian datetime to a timestamp
function toTimestamp($dt)
{
    $format = 'Y.m.d H:i:s.';
    
    if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '7.3.0', '<')) {
        $dt = explode('.', $dt);
        $dt[3] = intval($dt[3] * 1000);
        $dt = implode('.', $dt);

        $format .= 'u';
    } else {
        $format .= 'v';
    }

    return DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $dt)->getTimestamp();
}

$timestamp = toTimestamp('2020.07.22 22:41:36.258');
var_dump($timestamp);
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct format is stored in the `$format` variable:
(Note: the `v` (millisec) modifier has only been added since v7.3)

```
<?php
$format = 'Y.m.d H:i:s.v';
$dtime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, "2020.07.22 22:41:36.258");
$timestamp = $dtime->getTimestamp();
echo("Result: " . $timestamp . "<br>");
?>
```

```
Result: 1595457696
```

Comment: I'm trying to run your script here... [link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_strtotime) but it does not give any result.

Comment: you have to tell that `v` (milisec) modifier has only been added since v7.3

Comment: @SzakiLaci Please see the comment. Version 7.3 or higher is needed in order to use the `v` formatter.

Comment: So basically it's impossible to do it in PHP 5 ?

Comment: Is it possible, the this site is still running on PHP 5 too ? [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp)